# AsyncUA Variables With String Node ID

Tags: python-asyncio, opc-ua

How do I create a variable with a string node ID in asyncua rather than a numeric index?

In this instance it would be better to have a human readable node ID.

Thanks in advance, I have searched all through the internet and their GitHub trying to figure this out with no luck haha.